# HikariCP Idle connections staying in connection pool as active

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, hikaricp, connection-pool

I am using Spring Boot (1.5.6), Hibernate, Postgres, Hikari (2.7.8) . My configuration is :

```
spring.datasource.hikari.minimumIdle=1
spring.datasource.hikari.maximumPoolSize=20
spring.datasource.hikari.idleTimeout=30000
spring.datasource.hikari.poolName=SpringBootJPAHikariCP
spring.datasource.hikari.maxLifetime=50000
spring.datasource.hikari.connectionTimeout=30000
```

What I expect is, Idle connections should be released after `30000` ms/ 30 sec of idleness.
The problem is with every request new connection being made leaving all the idle connection as it is. So after some times I end up with 20 idle connection and with a new request Hikari try to gain a new connection and get `SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Connection is not available, request timed out after 30001ms.`

So, What I am doing wrong.? Or Have the misunderstood the configuration?

Hikari initialization Log:

```
SpringBootJPAHikariCP - configuration:
 allowPoolSuspension.............false
 autoCommit......................true
 catalog.........................none
 connectionInitSql...............none
 connectionTestQuery.............none
 connectionTimeout...............30000
 dataSource......................none
 dataSourceClassName.............none
 dataSourceJNDI..................none
 dataSourceProperties............{password=<masked>}
 driverClassName................."org.postgresql.Driver"
 healthCheckProperties...........{}
 healthCheckRegistry.............none
 idleTimeout.....................30000
 initializationFailFast..........true
 initializationFailTimeout.......1
 isolateInternalQueries..........false
 jdbc4ConnectionTest.............false
 jdbcUrl.........................jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/dbname
 leakDetectionThreshold..........0
 maxLifetime.....................50000
 maximumPoolSize.................20
 metricRegistry..................none
 metricsTrackerFactory...........none
 minimumIdle.....................1
 password........................<masked>
 poolName........................"SpringBootJPAHikariCP"
 readOnly........................false
 registerMbeans..................false
 scheduledExecutor...............none
 scheduledExecutorService........internal
 schema..........................none
 threadFactory...................internal
 transactionIsolation............default
 username........................"postgres"
 validationTimeout...............5000
```

**Update:**
In last 24 hour I have tried several solution from different thread and none of them fixed my issue. So here is the observations that might be important.

1. `SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Reset (autoCommit) on connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1344bbf1` found this log. studied 
   [Reset (autoCommit) on connection in HikariCP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41202242/reset-autocommit-on-connection-in-hikaricp) this thread. tried to set `auto commit` same (true) at both side (hibernate and Hikari) and tried with false at both side also. still no luck.
2. Enables `leakDetectionThreshold`, got leak detection exception. So tried to understand if hibernate/spring transaction manager releasing connections. From bellow Logs it looks like hibernate working fine.

   ```
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager-371 ::  Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4212be39] for JPA transaction
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl-51 ::  begin
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager-403 ::  Exposing JPA transaction as JDBC transaction [org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect$HibernateConnectionHandle@243e942]
   2com.someentity.MyEntity#ac918eed-345f-4a6c-8539-fe14e7fc41e2
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl-137 ::  Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - c.zaxxer.hikari.pool.ProxyConnection-242 ::  SpringBootJPAHikariCP - Executed rollback on connection org.postgresql.jdbc.PgConnection@1344bbf1 due to dirty commit state on close().
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener-132 ::  Processing flush-time cascades
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.e.i.AbstractFlushingEventListener-174 ::  Dirty checking collections

   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl-508 ::  Disconnecting session
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager-759 ::  Initiating transaction commit
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager-512 ::  Committing JPA transaction on EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4212be39]
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl-62 ::  committing
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl-137 ::  Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.r.j.i.LogicalConnectionManagedImpl-137 ::  Initiating JDBC connection release from afterTransaction
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.s.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager-600 ::  Closing JPA EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4212be39] after transaction
   28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.s.o.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryUtils-435 ::  Closing JPA EntityManager
   ```
3. All the idle connectiona are `idle` form `postgres` point of view and **`active`** form Hikari point of view. So when there are 5 idle connection from database, there are `toatal = 5, active=4, idle = ,waiting=0`  in Hikari log.

**Note:**

1. may be I am having this exact issue https://github.com/brettwooldridge/HikariCP/issues/109 in my case active connection increasing with every transaction.
2. [HikariCP - connection is not available](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32968530/hikaricp-connection-is-not-available) this is also a same issue. but nobody provide clear solution to this. btw I was using `@Transactional` from the begging as suggested by the accepted answer.

Comment: Your code is not returning connections to the pool. This has nothing to do with idleTimeout configuration setting.

Comment: how do i resolve this then. any suggestion or resource to read.? btw i am pretty new in connection pool matter.

Comment: Enable the ``leakDetectionThreshold`` and watch the log for leak stacktraces.

Comment: after enabling  `leakDetectionThreshold` got several leak detection exception. so possibly it is not the pool it self, may be my application doing something wrong.  still open to suggestions

Comment: @brettw can you please check my update on the question. still stuck with the issue.

Comment: Is your configuration opening and closing EntityManagers constantly?  Your log kind of implies that it does, eg. ``Opened new EntityManager [org.hibernate.jpa.internal.EntityManagerImpl@4212be39] for JPA transaction
28 22:19:35- DEBUG - o.h.e.t.internal.TransactionImpl-51``.  Also, ``autoCommit`` should definintely be ``false``.

Comment: @Saif pls create an issue / comment your details at `HikariCP` github repository , hope the  `HikariCP`  community will be able to solve this Or guide you to a solution

Comment: thank you @brettw for the suggestion. Solved this problem afterwards, could not post because of missing details. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This was not any Hikari issue, there was a mistake in my end. Still posting the details of how this occurred, in case it helps someone.

I was using `spring boot 1.5.6` (This was the latest version when I start working).
This version included `spring-orm 4.3.1`. This version of `spring-orm` included support for three versions of hibernate, `Hibernate5`, `Hibernate4` and `Hibernate3`.

So I configured spring boot with bellow configuration for `current_session_context_class`.

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

Everything was working fine until it comes to connection management of Hikari. What happened is `spring-boot-starter-jpa` for 1.5.6 included `Hibernate5` (I mean hibernate core) .

So, After performing any DB operation spring loosing control of that connection (most possibility for this version mismatch). Hence the problem.

After changing

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate4.SpringSessionContext
```

to

```
org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
```

the problem was solved immediately.

My current configuration is

```
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.current_session_context_class=org.springframework.orm.hibernate5.SpringSessionContext
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQL95Dialect
```

FYI, after solving the problem is switched to Spring Boot 2.

Comment: Hello @saif can you suggest configuration for me because after reading your post also i am not able to fix my hikari pool issue

Comment: Try adding maxLifeTime parameter to your hikariPool

Comment: @saif We have similar issue and we are using `spring-boot-starter-parent` version `2.3.8.RELEASE`. How do we identify if there is mismatch of Hibernate version? Please guide